# How to read huge file in Java, in chunks without being blocked?

Tags: java, multithreading

Say you have a file of bigger size then you have memory to handle. You'd like to read the files `n` bytes in turns **and** not get blocked in the process

- read a block
- pass it to a thread
- read another block
- pass it to a thread

I tried different things with varying success, however blocking always seem to be the issue.

Please provide an example of a *non-blocking way* to gain access to, say `byte[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

You will *always* block while waiting for the disk to provide you with data. If you have a lot of work to do with each chunk of data, then using a second thread may help: that thread can perform CPU-intensive work on the data while the first thread is blocked waiting for the next read to complete.

But that doesn't sound like your situation.

Your best bet is to read data in as large a block as you possibly can (say, 1MB or more). This minimizes the time blocked in the kernel, and may result in less time waiting for the disk (if the blocks being read happen to be contiguous).

---

Here's teh codez

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

// use RandomAccessFile because it supports readFully()
RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("myfile.dat", "r");
in.seek(0L);

while (in.getFilePointer() < in.length())
{
    int readSize = (int)Math.min(1000000, in.length() - in.getFilePointer());
    final byte[] data = new byte[readSize];
    in.readFully(data);
    exec.execute(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            // do something with data
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Right. Lets say i read 1M at a time. After i read it (and placed in say a byte[]), i'd like to pass it to another thread **before** i read in another 1M.

Comment: And your problem with this is?

Comment: `while(whatever) { byte[] chunk = new byte[1 << 10]; myInputStream.read(chunk); executorService.submit(theTaskUsing(chunk)); }`

Comment: "that thread can perform CPU-intensive work on the data while the first thread is blocked waiting for the next read to complete" but perhaps not, if the O/S does some read-ahead and you buffer the input yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for Streams, buffering, or some combination of the two (BufferedInputStream anyone?).

Check this out:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html

This is the standard way to deal with very large files. I apologize if this isn't what you were looking for, but hopefully it'll help get the juices flowing anyway.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a program that does I/O and CPU computations, blocking is inevitable (somewhere in your program) if on average the amount of CPU time it takes to process a byte is less than the time to read a byte.

If you try to read a file and that requires a disk seek, the data might not arrive for 10 ms. A 2 GHz CPU could have done 20 M clock cycles of work in that time.